# Chart.js time-based bar chart

Tags: javascript, time, chart.js

I would like to know if this is possible to do with Chart.js. I have not been able to figure it out.

Basically, I want a horizontal bar chart where time is on the X axis, and the bars have data that is a start date/time and end date/time, such that the bars "float" and are not anchored to the left side of the chart. The bar would start at the start time and end at the end time, as labeled on the x axis.

Also, I need the y axis labels to be inside the horizontal bar.

Does Chart.js support this use case? Does anyone have sample code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they support floating bars (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/floating.html) if you add the property `indexAxis: 'y'` in the options object it will become a horizontal bar chart. to get the labels in the bars you will need to use the datalabels plugin: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html